# Are these two functions equal to each other?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maximum-likelihood

Say I need to optimize this function $\underset{a,b}{\operatorname{argmax}} g(a,b)$, where $g(a,b)\geq 0  \ \forall a,b$. Could I transform it into $\underset{a}{\operatorname{argmax}}(\underset{b}{\operatorname{argmax} g(a,b)})$ where $g(a,b)\geq 0 \   \forall a,b$ ? If yes, can it be proved?

Comment: This is known as alternating optimization.. Fixing $a$, while maximizing with respect to $b$

Comment: So you mean they are equal?

Comment: Did you try something to prove they are?

Comment: Not always .. i will try to explain below @deathlee

Comment: The value of the inner argmax is a $b$, do you really want the outer argmax to maximize $b$?